# Boost Timer in Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I'm trying to create  qt application that uses a timer from boost, 
I have a problem with the following code 
Compiled on osx, qt 5.2, boost 1.55

This is my code:

```
CCTimer::CCTimer(int interval)
    : m_pingTimer(m_ioServiceTimer, boost::posix_time::seconds(interval)), m_interval(interval)
{
    m_isRunning = false;
}

CCTimer::~CCTimer()
{
    Stop();
}

void CCTimer::Start()
{
    if(!m_isRunning)
    {
        m_isRunning = true;
        Reset(m_interval);
        m_timerThread = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &m_ioServiceTimer)));
    }
}

void CCTimer::Reset(int durationTime)
{
    m_beforeTime = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
    m_pingTimer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(durationTime));
    m_pingTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&CCTimer::Wait, this, _1));
}

void CCTimer::Wait(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode)
{
    boost::posix_time::time_duration duration = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() - m_beforeTime;
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() << std::endl;
    if(duration.seconds() > m_interval) {
        std::cout << "Error time " << std::endl;
    }
    Reset(m_interval);
}

void CCTimer::Stop()
{
    if(m_isRunning)
    {
        m_isRunning = false;
        m_pingTimer.cancel();
        m_ioServiceTimer.stop();
        m_timerThread->join();
        m_ioServiceTimer.reset();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    CCTimer timer(1);
    timer.Start();

    return app.exec();
}
```

After creation of the timer in qt application, console shows:

```
2014-Mar-26 22:04:30.549722
2014-Mar-26 22:04:31.550977
2014-Mar-26 22:04:32.552229
2014-Mar-26 22:04:33.553467
2014-Mar-26 22:04:34.554734
2014-Mar-26 22:04:43.684300
Error time 
2014-Mar-26 22:04:54.694440
Error time 
2014-Mar-26 22:05:05.694371
Error time 
2014-Mar-26 22:05:11.669329
Error time
```

what can be wrong ?

Comment: What did you expect it to give?

Comment: Wait function should be performed every 1s but after a while this time will be longer

Comment: I think there's a typo. "Hammer" was misspelled there.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't spotted anything glaring. Though, of course, you never mention whether/when/where you class `Stop()` and `Start()`.

I made the implementation marginally simpler and fixed a few potential races:

- no useless use of shared pointer for the time thread
- make the CCTimer non-copyable
- no more `m_isRunning` kludge; instead, intentionally cancel the timer and detect cancellation so you can end the thread. If the thread is `joinable()`, it's running
- fixed a race condition where you cancel the timer from the thread that calls `Stop()`, whereas the timer is being async-awaited by the io_service thread, byt posting the cancel to the io_service thread too:

  ```
  void Stop()
  {
      if(m_thread.joinable())
      {
          m_service.post(boost::bind(&deadline_timer::cancel, &m_timer));
          m_thread.join();
          m_service.stop();
          m_service.reset();
      }
  }
  ```
- fixed a cosmetic thing that could have led to confusion where you use a different timestamp for printing than you do for calculating the elapsed time

**Update**

So I downloaded Qt5 and goaded my compiler to use it. /GREAT SUCCESS/. And indeed, I got the same behaviour (but far worse, sometimes). The strange thing was it blocked more on the terminal than the eventual output would show. This made me suspect it's maybe Qt that's intercepting/reopening the stdin/stdout streams for it's own purposes and adding some blocking/buffering behaviour in the process.

I checked this by writing the timer trace to a separate file instead, and indeed this removed the symptoms (when left running for over hald an hour). So this is likely the cause of your issue. **Just don't write to stdout from your timer thread and your spurious blocking issue should be gone**.

Here's the code I used to test this, with the above suggestions incorporated:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <fstream>

using namespace boost::asio;
namespace pt = boost::posix_time;

class CCTimer : boost::noncopyable
{
    io_service     m_service;
    deadline_timer m_timer;
    pt::ptime      m_starttime;
    int            m_interval_seconds;
    boost::thread  m_thread;
    std::ofstream  ofs;

  public:
    CCTimer(int interval)
        : m_service(),
          m_timer(m_service), 
          m_interval_seconds(interval)
    {
        assert(m_interval_seconds>0);
    }

    ~CCTimer()
    {
        Stop();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if(!m_thread.joinable())
        {
            ofs.open("output.log");
            Reset(m_interval_seconds);
            m_thread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&io_service::run, &m_service));
        }
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        if(m_thread.joinable())
        {
            m_service.post(boost::bind(&deadline_timer::cancel, &m_timer));
            m_thread.join();
            ofs.close();
            m_service.stop();
            m_service.reset();
        }
    }

  private:
    static pt::ptime now() { return pt::microsec_clock::universal_time(); }

    void Reset(int durationTime)
    {
        m_timer.expires_from_now(pt::seconds(durationTime));
        m_starttime = now();
        m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&CCTimer::Elapsed, this, placeholders::error));
    }

    void Elapsed(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode)
    {
        pt::ptime const event           = now();
        pt::time_duration const elapsed = event - m_starttime;

        if (errorCode != error::operation_aborted && ofs.is_open() && ofs.good())
        {
            ofs << event << " (" << elapsed.total_milliseconds() << "ms) ";

            if(elapsed.seconds() > m_interval_seconds) {
                ofs << " Overdue!" << std::endl;
            } else {
                ofs << "" << std::endl;
            }

            Reset(m_interval_seconds);
        } else
        {
            ofs << "Stopped (" << elapsed.total_milliseconds() << "ms)" << std::endl;
        }
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    CCTimer timer(1);
    timer.Start();

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

Old suggestions:

I'd have to assume you're doing something in the rest of the code that inhibits the CCTimer thread

- are you running under a debugger, profiler, whatnot?
- are you running under a (overwhelmed) virtualizer?
- are you doing more on the same `io_service`/thread?
- can IO be blocking? In particular do you log the timestamps to an actual console or to a file/pipe? Could the output pipe be blocking the timer thread?

Comment: Here's output from a typical test run under fuzzing: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7159983/

Comment: This is not working when i use this in qt application.
2014-Mar-27 09:44:14.659332 (3000ms) 
2014-Mar-27 09:44:17.660465 (3000ms) 
2014-Mar-27 09:44:20.660964 (3000ms) 
2014-Mar-27 09:44:23.661534 (3000ms) 
2014-Mar-27 09:44:26.662573 (3000ms) 
2014-Mar-27 09:44:39.662341 (12999ms)  Overdue!
2014-Mar-27 09:44:52.662087 (12999ms)  Overdue!
2014-Mar-27 09:44:59.975114 (7312ms)  Overdue!

Comment: Well. What does the application do? Is it **just** the code in your question? I might try to install Qt for that then.

Comment: It's very weird behavior, if i run your timer without qt everything works correctly, but if i connect it with qt, timer stops working.

Comment: You didn't answer my question?

Comment: Application do nothing it's simple hello world app, and contains only the code from my question

Comment: So, it's /not/ a "hello world" app then :). I'll have a look later.

Comment: @user3115083 Ahahah. I reproduced it _and_ worked around it. I was on the right track with that last hunch: _" can IO be blocking? In particular do you log the timestamps to an actual console or to a file/pipe? Could the output pipe be blocking the timer thread?"_. Cheers.

Comment: I tried your code, but it does not work. 
output.log contains
2014-Mar-28 12:16:27.717202 (1000ms) 
2014-Mar-28 12:16:28.718113 (1000ms) 
2014-Mar-28 12:16:29.719334 (1000ms) 
2014-Mar-28 12:16:40.719208 (10999ms)  Overdue!
2014-Mar-28 12:16:51.719012 (10999ms)  Overdue!
2014-Mar-28 12:16:57.485430 (5766ms)  Overdue!

Comment: @user3115083 interesting. FWIW I was on ubuntu 13.10 with Qt  5.0.2+dfsg1-7ubuntu11.1

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong.
maybe osx has only issue with it

Comment: I suggest taking it to the Qt issue trackers. This is now rather well-researched, you have minimal reproducers and we can't solve it.